# out / ref parameter for delegate

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Delegate:

```
return delegate( IQueryable<MySearchResultItem> query, Expression<Func<MySearchResultItem, object>> lambda, Wrapper wrapper)
{
    wrapper.query = query.OrderBy(lambda);
    query = query.OrderBy(lambda);
};
```

Wrapper class:

```
public class Wrapper
{
    public IQueryable<MySearchResultItem> query { get; set; }
}
```

When I execute this delegate I expected for the query to be changed after this function is over, but it didn't. So i assume that the query passed by value ( instead of by reference )

But when I create a wrapper class for this query, add the query to the wrapper class and pass this along as well. Then after this method is done the query inside the wrapper class has been changed ( so this wrapper class was passed by reference ? )

What's going on here ?

Comment: You assign query anew to query.OrderBy(lambda). Would that not create a  new reference, and the input query parameter would thereby not have changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be mixing up C# "by reference" with C++ "by reference".

In your code, `query` is passed by reference, which means that the reference to the value of `query` is passed by value. Thus, changing `query` will change the value the reference is referencing. However, changing the reference itself does nothing.

`query` is immutable - there's no way to change the value. You can only create a new query, that contains the old query within itself. And that's exactly what e.g. `OrderBy` does - it doesn't change the `query`. This is one of the core features of LINQ and similar functional approaches in C# - mutable code is generally much harder to deal with in a general way, so you want to avoid it, especially on interfaces.

So what you need to do is pass the reference by reference, not by value. That's exactly what you've done by providing the `Wrapper` class. It's also possible to use `ref` keyword to do this, but it's completely unnecessary and rather hard to deal with in your case. `ref` only really makes sense with value types, though there are useful cases even for reference types; they are quite rare, though.

But the best and easiest approach is to simply follow the simple principle: don't change anything, just return an object that contains the change. Make your delegate *return* the query, rather than modifying the argument:

```
delegate IQueryable<...> YourDelegate(IQueryable<...> query);

IQueryable<...> YourMethod(IQueryable<...> query)
{
  return query.OrderBy(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is passed by reference, but you are not operating on the reference but rather overwrite it. It is like in C when you assign a new address to a pointer instead of operating on the value of the pointer. It works with the wrapper class, because you work on the reference instead of overwriting it.

If you want to modify the reference as well use the `ref` operator.

```
return delegate( ref IQueryable<MySearchResultItem> query,
```

**Edit:** Of course that requires to have matching delegate signature and it won't work with `Func<T1,T2, TResult>`.

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(ref IQueryable<object> query, Expression<Func<object, object>> lambda);

private MyDelegate Create()
{
    return delegate(ref IQueryable<object> query, Expression<Func<object, object>> lambda)
    {
        query = query.OrderBy(lambda);
    };
}
```

Comment: That gives me this error: "Parameter 1 should not be declared with the 'ref' keyword"

Comment: @Timon Of course, because it's a *horrible idea* to do that. Just follow the common practice and *return* the new query like everyone else. You're dealing with functional programming, and the queries are immutable. Return a new thing, don't change the old thing.

Comment: Could you please post the Rest of your code then? It assume you have to match a certain signature for the delegate.

Comment: @Luaan I agree that this is a horrible idea. However I assumed when he did not write an extension he had his reasons. So all I did was try to explain why whatever he wants to do, does not work.